# Why is telnetlib continuing to write to file after tn.close statement? Also, it's sending my command twice

Tags: python, telnetlib

This script is supposed to open a telnet session with a remote device, send a command, and write the output to a file. The CC and CA stand for Ctrl + C and Ctrl + A. The only possible explanation that I can come up with is that the remote device is not sending the Ctrl+C at the end, but the shell output shows that it is.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#Import external modules
import sys
import socket
import telnetlib
import datetime
import csv
import logging
import os

#Import internal variables and functions
from ctrlchar import CA,CC

#import csv file siteProfiles.csv
with open("/home/dev/iotank/site-profiles-staging.csv") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        data = []
        for row in  reader:
                data.append(row)

#Variables
TIMEOUT=30 #Telnet timeout in seconds
#251 is CSLD Report, 301 Liquid Sensor Status Report, 201 is Inventory Report
COMMAND="I201"
DEVICE="00"
DATE=datetime.date.today()
TIME=datetime.datetime.now()
TIMESTAMP=TIME.strftime("%m%d%Y%H%M")
sites = len(data)
logging.basicConfig(filename='log.txt',level=logging.DEBUG)
logger= logging.getLogger("basiclog")
REPORTNAME="TESTFI" + TIMESTAMP + ".txt" 
file = open("/home/dev/iotank/report/inventory/" + REPORTNAME, 'w+')
for row in xrange(sites):
        SITE = data[row][0]
        HOST = data[row][1]
        PORT = data[row][2]
        BEGINREPORT=COMMAND + DEVICE
        try:
                tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST,PORT,TIMEOUT)
                tn.set_debuglevel(1)
                tn.write(CA)
                tn.write(COMMAND)
                tn.write(DEVICE)
                tn.read_until("TEMP")
                file.write("z" + SITE + "\r\n" + TIMESTAMP)
                file.write(tn.read_until(CC))
                tn.close
                file.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END)
                file.truncate()
        except Exception:
                logger.error(SITE + HOST + "Couldn't connect", exc_info=True)
file.close()
```

Output:

```
z080
121720190130
  1  ULTRA LOW DIESEL     12175         0     2929    90.17     1.70    63.77
  2  DYED LSDF             3345         0      970    65.44     0.00    63.61
  3  UNLEAD                1002         0     5014    21.44     0.00    70.17
  4  SUPER                 1078         0     2901    30.33     1.69    70.19
^A
I20100
DEC 17, 2019  2:27 AM

US 280 FUEL CENTER




IN-TANK INVENTORY

TANK PRODUCT             VOLUME TC VOLUME   ULLAGE   HEIGHT    WATER     TEMP
  1  ULTRA LOW DIESEL     12175         0     2929    90.17     1.70    63.79
  2  DYED LSDF             3345         0      970    65.44     0.00    63.61
  3  UNLEAD                1002         0     5014    21.44     0.00    70.15
  4  SUPER                 1078         0     2901    30.33     1.69    70.20
```

The top 6 lines before the Ctrl+A character is the desired output. Why does the code continue through another iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You need parentheses after the `tn.close`. Python isn't like Ruby or Lua, you have to explicitly call the function.

```py
tn.close # gives the value of the function (<bound method Whatever.close of <Whatever object at 0x0000d15ea5e>>
tn.close() # calls the function
```

Comment: Thanks that was useful; however the output was the same. I changed the line:            
 file.write(tn.read_until("\x03")) to  file.write(tn.read_until("\r\n\r\n"))

Comment: Changing the tn.read_until statement did not fix the issues. Either the script loops 2x on the same parameter(not likely) or the device answers twice. Either way the read_until statement should prevent duplication, but it does not.